# What is the saturation property of molecular forces?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, statistical-mechanics

**Context**

I'm studying statistical mechanics using Huang's *Statistical Mechanics* [1]. Huang writes,

> Empricially $U$ is an extensive quantity. This follows from the saturation property of molecular forces, namely that the energy of a substance is doubled if its mass is doubled.

I searched for saturation property and did not find much immediately accessible material on the web. I also searched this site and found one question with the terms *saturation property* that appears to have the same sense as that used by Huang [10].

My intuition thinks that this saturation property has to do with how close the charged particles are that form the bulk material and with the electrostatic potential energy stored therein. Therefore, doubling the amount of material doubles the electrostatic potential energy.

**Question**

Can you clarify what this saturation property is with a little bit more rigor that what is given in the quote above?

**Bibliography**

[1] Kerson Huang, Statistical Mechanics, Wiley and Sons, 1987, p 7.

[10] [saturation property of nuclear forces ? and its relation binding energy per nucleon constantcy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102528/saturation-property-of-nuclear-forces-and-its-relation-binding-energy-per-nucl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *saturation* is borrowed from nuclear physics, which, in turn, reused a concept of condensed matter where, at a first-order phase transition like the liquid-vapor transition, any attempt to increase the saturated vapor phase density fails for the formation of the corresponding liquid phase.

In nuclear physics, saturation of the nuclear forces is the mechanism justifying the constancy of the average nucleon density in the nucleus. If $A$ is the mass number (essentially the number of nucleons), and $R$ is the radius of the nucleus as measured by scattering experiments, the average nucleon density $\rho=A/V=3A/(4 \pi R^3)$ is close to a constant ($0.17 fm^{-3}$)for all but the lightest elements. The explanation (and partly the reason for the name) is that strong forces between nucleons display a harsh repulsion at very short distances, followed by a short-range strong attraction. Combining the two features implies that **on average, every nucleon interacts with a fixed number of other nucleons** for a large enough nucleus. As a consequence, the cohesive energy grows linearly with the mass number.

The same phenomenon (the fixed number of effectively interacting units) is at the basis of the extensiveness of the thermodynamic internal energy. As you will see studying Huang's book, to recover the classic thermodynamic properties from statistical mechanics, interactions must be such that the so-called *Thermodynamic Limit* (TL) exists. A fundamental property to ensure the TL is the presence of an upper bound to the number of effectively interacting units when their number grows. An example of non-saturating interaction is a pair interaction based on an attractive well at short distances without repulsion.
With a pair potential like
$$
\phi(r) = -C~~~{\mathrm {for}}~~~r<\sigma~~~~{\mathrm {and~zero~elsewhere}}
$$
with $C$ a positive constant, we could have $N$ the particles within a distance  $\sigma$, resulting in energy going as the number of pairs ($\simeq N^2$). A system like this fails to have TL. A harsh repulsion introduces an upper limit to the number of first neighbors. If the interaction is not long-range, the total number of particles interacting with a given one *saturates*, and extensiveness follows.